# can a mobile application developed for io6 work correctly on ios7 and ios8?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, ios8

Could you please indicate us if an Mobile Application developed for iOS6 can work correctly (without any adaptation) on iOS 7 and 8 or there will always be any functional and display issues and therefore it will be necessary to redevelop this Mobile Application for iOS 7 and 8.

Comment: It's dependent on the app itself, how it was written and what kind of iOS features it uses.  You'll need to test to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iOS6 application might run correctly without any problem.
It might also show some visual problems (iOS6 did not cater for the new iphone6/6+ formats or even 3x retina displays), or could fail (crashes) because it's using deprecated functionalities. As suggested, the best you can do is test your application with those newer iOS versions, there's no straight answer to that question.

If your application is not already on the AppStore, but you have its source code and would like to submit it at some point in the future, it will most likely need to be reworked because the submission process will check for compliance with newer i-devices.